# Express.js "path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile" error

Tags: node.js, express

NOTE : This is NOT a duplicate question, I've already tried other answers to similar questions.

I'm trying to render html files (Angular) but I'm having an issue.
This works.

```
app.get('/randomlink', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/views/" + "test2.html" );
});
```

But I don't want to copy and paste dirname thingy over and over, so I tried this in order to not to be repetitive with urls:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.get('/randomlink', function(req, res) {
     res.sendFile('test2.html'); // test2.html exists in the views folder
 });
```

Here's the error.

My express version is 4.13

> path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't go against official documentation of [res.sendFile()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

> Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file.

But I understand that you don't want to copy smth like `__dirname` every time, and so for your purpose I think you can define your own middleware:

```
function sendViewMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    res.sendView = function(view) {
        return res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/" + view);
    }
    next();
}
```

After that you can easily use this middleware like this

```
app.use(sendViewMiddleware);

app.get('/randomlink', function(req, res) {
    res.sendView('test2.html');
});
```

Answer (score 14):

If you look into the express code for sendFile, then it checks for this condition:

```
if (!opts.root && !isAbsolute(path)) {
    throw new TypeError('path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile');
}
```

So You must need to pass Absolute path or relative path with providing `root` key.

```
res.sendFile('test2.html', { root: '/home/xyz/code/'});
```

And if you want to use relative path and then you can make use `path.resolve` to make it absolute path.

```
var path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.resolve('test2.html'));
```

Comment: This was what I needed. I had to go back a step back in the directory with a `./path` and the `__dirname` wasn't offering that flexibilty, or maybe I wasn't doing it right, but path is gorgeos!

Comment: But now the `root` option has to be absolute! In my case the node file is in a subfolder, it needs to serve a file that is one directory higher.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to specify the root:

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
```

Comment: But what if `__dirname` is not the root?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem then i solved my issue as follows.

```
const path = require("path")
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html"))
}
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

the issue happened to me when I was providing subpaths. I set static path and had this route:

```
const public = path.join(__dirname, "..", "live", "public");

app.get("*", (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```

Visiting "/" path worked but "/anyOtherPath" did not work. So I change the route:

```
app.get("*", (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(public + "/index.html");
});
```