# Having trouble with the node express API

Tags: express, localhost, sendfile

I've tried [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-a-chat-application-with-mean-stack-637254d1136d/) tutorial on how to set up a localhost, and some code worked, some didn't. But currently I am receiving strange experience with it:

Below in the code at `res.sendfile` it's important to mention that the terminal comments this command as deprecated.

Using `res.sendFile` gives however the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217044/express-js-path-must-be-absolute-or-specify-root-to-res-sendfile-error/34217193) error.

I've tried to use `.sendFile` with the absolute path, but it didn't work:

```
res.sendFile('localhost:3000/client/index.html');
```

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('client/index.html');
});
```

I am just trying to make a simple connection between the server.js and the index.html. The expected output is to have `index.html` displayed instead of the error.

Comment: `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');`

Comment: Oh wait, seriously? I saw this answer everywhere, but I primarily thought it must be replaced by the absolute link. I thought it was undefined. Oh god...

Thank you very much for the answer! I guess we can lock this now?

Comment: You want me to post it as an answer ?

Comment: @StephenS That would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `__dirname` variable which stores the absolute path of the current executing script. You can append this path in the `sendFile` function.

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
```

Alternatively you can use the Node.js `path` module for joining paths

```
const path = require('path');
...
...
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/client/index.html'));
```

`path.join` ensures correct slashes in case of UNIX / Windows systems.